# Why am I unable to spread an object in my mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This might be a silly question but why on earth am I getting an "Unexpected token" error for the following code snippet? Bear in mind it is a mongoose model.

**Error message**

```
SyntaxError: D:/Coding/Species Project/backend/models/species.js: Unexpected token (15:2)
  13 |  },
  14 |  organism: {
> 15 |          ...shared,
     |          ^
  16 |          enum: ["Plant", "Animal", "Other"],
  17 |  },
  18 |  taxonomy: {
```

**Mongoose model**

```
const shared = {
    type: String,
    required: true,
}

const SpeciesSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        common: shared,
        scientific: shared,
    },
    organism: {
        ...shared,
        enum: ["Plant", "Animal", "Other"],
    },
    ...,
}
```

Comment: Is that last `...,` part of your actual code, or just an example? Also, what is the unexpected token?

Comment: No, it's not. I added the ellipsis simply to imply continuation of the code. Also, I edited the question to include the error message.

Comment: Does your node version support the use of the rest/spread operator with objects?

Comment: @PatrickEvans It does, which is why it's a rather unexpected result.

Comment: If that's your error message, I would double-check your Node version. Looks like [8.6.0](http://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties-object-spread-properties) is the first version that supports it properly. What you have written should be valid.

Comment: @samanime I'm on 9.4. Hell, not even babel-polyfill solves the issue.

Comment: The only other possible thing I can think of that would cause this would be that the `...` aren't actually periods but some other character. Have you tried deleting that whole part and manually retyping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread operator is used as parameters from array.

You might want to use this, instead

```
const SpeciesSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        common: shared,
        scientific: shared,
    },
    organism: Object.assign({}, shared, enum: ["Plant", "Animal", "Other"]},
    ...,
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Object.assign works. However, it is rather verbose, which is what I was looking to avoid to begin with.